# How can I get the Tridion Installation Path?

Tags: 2011

We have a SDL Tridion installation on Windows Server 2008 R2. We want to get the path of the Tridion Installation home folder programatically in the Event System.

Is there an Environment Variable or setting we can read through TOM.NET API or C# code to get this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can us the below generic code to get the installation path of SDL Tridion (it looks you are using SDL Tridion 2011 as specified by the question tag) regardless of the fact whether you are using a 32-bit OS or 64-Bit OS:

```
      private string GetTridionInstallPath()
      {
         string output = string.Empty;
         string regKeyPath = string.Empty;
         if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
         {
             regKeyPath = @"Software\Wow6432Node\Tridion";
         }
         else
         {
             regKeyPath = @"Software\Tridion";
         }
         RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKeyPath);
         output = regKey.GetValue("InstallDir").ToString();

         return output;
      }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your quick reply; I will surely give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This will work (I used this code regularly before, see http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetTridionInstallPath) but it might break between versions. Recommended to use GetTcmHomeDirectory() or %TRIDION_CM_HOME% instead.

Comment: Thanks Nuno, for me at least, this is really valuable information that you have shared, to be very frank, I was not aware about GetTcmHomeDirectory function.
I would be taking care of it in future and I totally agree, my above code would not be version proof (that why, explicitly mentioned the version as 2011 :P )

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

- `Tridion.ContentManager.ConfigurationSettings.GetTcmHomeDirectory();`
- `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TRIDION_CM_HOME");`
- Any of the other methods already mentioned.

If you have the option, use the GetTcmHomeDirectory() method, since that's the one used by Tridion itself.

Answer (score 8):

I think the following environment variable will work.

```
%TRIDION_CM_HOME%
```

You can get this in C# using [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I refer you to the ["GetTridionInstallPath" recipe](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetTridionInstallPath) contributed by Frank van Puffellen to the Tridion Cookbook at Tridion Practice. If you also include the comment by Peter Kjaer, it covers all the techniques mentioned here so far.

It's actually the first hit if you Google for "get tridion installation path".